# WPF showing control with DataTrigger skips it in TabOrder

Tags: wpf, xaml, datatrigger, tab-ordering

I would like to show 'additional details' Textbox when the previous `TextBox`'s value is not 0.00 (zero). This is easily accomplished with DataTriggers:

```
<TextBox Name="FirstTB" Text="{Binding Amount, StringFormat=F2}"/><!--when this TB is not 0-->
<TextBox Name="SecondTB"> <!--show this TB-->
    <TextBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Amount}" Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>
<TextBox Name="ThirdTB"/>
```

The issue is, however, when changing value of `FirstTB` to <> 0 and pressing `Tab` the focus jumps to the **ThirdTB** instead of **SecondTB** (even though `SecondTB` now is Visible due to the DataTrigger). How can I fix this issue?

---

Sadly, `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` does not appear to be an option due to its interference with `StringFormat`s - it gives terrible UX when you are editing the value, carret jumps around like crazy due to constant StringFormat evaluation. Viewmodel used in example above:

```
public class MyVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private double _amount;
    public double Amount
    {
        get { return _amount; }
        set
        {
            _amount = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Amount)));
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean with the interference with string format ? this is possible: `<TextBox Name="FirstTB" Text="{Binding Amount, StringFormat=F2, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>`

Comment: Have you tried with `IsTabStop="True" TabIndex="1"`

Comment: @NawedNabiZada I am tasked to avoid `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` at all costs because it gives terrible UX - when you are editing the value, carret jumps around like crazy due to constant StringFormat evaluation.

Comment: Ok this makes sense... Perhaps add it to the question, as it was not clear what you actually meant

Comment: @NawedNabiZada good idea. Sadly, setting explicit TabOrder had no effect, it is still skipped (just tried it).

Comment: The next thing I can think of is to assign to the IsVisibilityChanged event handler and focus that text box. Having code in your View for View only purposes does not break MVVM.

Comment: @NawedNabiZada another good idea, however it does not work neither - still it is the `ThirdTB` which gets the focus. Logging PreviewFocus changed gives  FirstTB->ThirdTB->SecondTB->ThirdTB so WPF for some weird reason immedietly forces focus back.

Comment: @wondra, `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` can be a solution, if you combine it with [Binding.Delay](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.bindingbase.delay?view=netframework-4.8): `Text="{Binding Amount, Delay=500, StringFormat=F2}"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a stupid work around. But this will do the work:

View:

```
<TextBox Name="SecondTB" IsVisibleChanged="SecondTB_OnIsVisibleChanged">
     <!--show this TB-->
     <TextBox.Style>
         <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
              <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Amount, Mode=OneWay}" Value="0">
                         <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
              </Style.Triggers>
         </Style>
    </TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>
```

C#:

```
private void SecondTB_OnIsVisibleChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (((bool) e.NewValue))
    {
        if(!(sender is TextBox txbx)) return;
        ThirdTB.GotFocus += ThirdTbOnGotFocus;
    }
}

private void ThirdTbOnGotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SecondTB.Focus();
    ThirdTB.GotFocus -= ThirdTbOnGotFocus;
}
```

Comment: Well, not the most elegant solution, but it does work - let me wait a day and I will accept it as an answer if there is no better one.

Answer (score 0):

If you use an `IValueConverter` you get a very elegant way for your problem. Everytime the value is changed, the logic is called.

```cs
public class IsZeroToHiddenConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is double d && d == 0)
            return Visibility.Hidden;
        return Visibility.Visible;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

You calso play around and add `ConverterParameter` to decide if you want `Collapsed` or `Hidden` behavior.

### Usage

```cs
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <local:IsZeroToHiddenConverter x:Key="IsZeroToHiddenConverter"/>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBox x:Name="Tb1" Grid.Row="0" Width="100" Margin="5" Text="{Binding Path=Amount, StringFormat=F2, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="Tb2" Grid.Row="1" Width="100" Margin="5" Visibility="{Binding Path=Amount, Converter={StaticResource IsZeroToHiddenConverter}}"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="Tb3" Grid.Row="2" Width="100" Margin="5"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

### Preview

[image]

Comment: Thanks for pointing alternative to DataTriggers, however Covnerters suffer from the very same issue: wont work unless there is `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` and due to UX we cannot use UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, it causes weird caret behaviour (jumps to last decimal place whenever Binding is evaluated). For example, when you select the text and attempt to type '1.5' it would display '1.5.00' instead and go red.